# What timezone does Excel in Office 365/Sharepoint use for TODAY/NOW functions?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, excel-365

When working on a Excel document in Sharepoint when I use the TODAY function I get odd results. It looks like the date is from the day before. I wonder what timezone does it use? Is that a setting or is it based on the browser I use?

(Context: I'm using Sharepoint on a Kubuntu 20.04 desktop)

Answer (score 0):

That based on the timezone you specify in site settings->Regional settings. As the below picture shows:

[image]

Comment: So it is up to my site administrator to make sure it's correct? Or can I fix this for me personally?

Comment: Yes, this is controlled by your site administrator. You can not change this on yourself.

Comment: Was this behavior changed recently? In my workbook the `=NOW()` formula returns time in the local timezone from my Windows Settings even though a different timezone is set in the site.