# How can I convert a Date() into an Excel Date Number?

Tags: swift, excel, date

For a conversation about Excels Date Format see [Is Excel date value time zone specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010958/is-excel-date-value-time-zone-specific). I'm using for exporting a CSV File the following Date Extension. It adjusts for Time Zone (current timezone must be same for the program and excel) and fixes the 29.1.1900 bug.

Answer (score 0):

Swift Date Extension to convert Date() into a Excel Date Value (Double):

```
//
//  ExcelDate+Extension.swift 
//  Created by Jean-Nicolas on 10.10.22.
//

import Foundation

extension Date {

  var excelDateValue: Double {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let timeZone = calendar.timeZone
    let excelDateComponent = DateComponents(year: 1900, month: 01, day: 01, hour: 1, minute: 0) // use 1 hour ! not 0
    var excelDate = calendar.date(from: excelDateComponent)!
    /* adjust to excel by subtracting 2 days!
        - 1 day for "beginning of  1.1.1900"
        - 1 day because of wrong leap day 29.2.1900.
     */
    excelDate = calendar.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day:-2), to: excelDate)!
    let secondsInterval = DateInterval(start: excelDate, end: self).duration
    /* adjust for time zone */
    let secondsFromGmt = Double(timeZone.secondsFromGMT())
    let excelSecondsInterval = secondsInterval + secondsFromGmt
    let secondsToDay: Double = (60 * 60 * 24)
    return excelSecondsInterval / secondsToDay
    
  }
}
```